Need .board and Flash File for STM32H745 with MT25QL512A in IAR
I am working on a project using the STM32H745 microcontroller with an MT25QL512A external QSPI flash. I am using IAR Embedded Workbench for development and require the following:
.board file: Specific to STM32H745 with MT25QL512A.
Flash loader file: A compatible flash configuration file for programming and debugging the external QSPI flash in IAR.
I’ve seen .stldr files provided by STM32CubeProgrammer, but these cannot be directly used in IAR. If anyone has successfully configured this setup in IAR or has access to the required .board and flash files, I would greatly appreciate your help.
Any examples or guidance on configuring QSPI for this combination in IAR would also be highly valuable.
Thank you in advance for your support!
I’ve attempted to use .stldr files provided by STM32CubeProgrammer for the MT25QL512A. However, these files cannot be directly used in IAR.
I manually configured the .board file but encountered errors during programming and debugging.
I created a .flash file and added it to the flash loader configuration in IAR. While this was recognized, I faced issues with memory mapping and the actual programming process.
I also experimented with .mac files for macro-based initialization, but the setup didn’t align with my specific configuration needs.
Challenges Encountered
Memory address mismatches between the QSPI flash and IAR configurations.
Debugging sessions failing to recognize the external QSPI flash loader, despite attempting custom loader files.
Request for Assistance
If you have successfully configured this setup or have access to the appropriate .board and flash loader files for STM32H745 with MT25QL512A in IAR, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Specifically, I’d like to know:
The correct method to adapt or create .flash, .board, and .mac files for this configuration.
Any modifications required in the IAR linker or project settings to ensure seamless debugging and programming.
Examples or tested files that I can reference.
Your support and expertise would save significant development time and help resolve these roadblocks. Please feel free to share any documentation or suggestions you think might help.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
